I need to get transaction receipt's certain event and their parameter values
I tried with following code but its not working. I'm trying to make helper functions which returns parameter values of event after transaction execution.
const receipt = await tx.wait();
const event = receipt.events.find((e) => e.event === "PoolCreated");
const lendingPoolAddress = event.args.pool;


Try receipt.logs instead of events

Possible Issues:

Event Emission: Ensure that the PoolCreated event is correctly emitted in your contract. Check if it's actually part of the transaction and logs.
Event Arguments: Confirm that the event includes an argument named pool (or whatever the correct name is in the contract's event definition).
Transaction Wait: Ensure that tx.wait() is correctly fetching the receipt after the transaction is mined.
Event Logs: Sometimes events may not be properly captured if the contract or address isn't linked correctly or if there are multiple events fired during the transaction.

Enhanced Code Example:
    const receipt = await tx.wait(); // Wait for the transaction to be mined

// Find the event you're looking for (PoolCreated in this case)
const event = receipt.events.find((e) => e.event === "PoolCreated");

if (event && event.args) {
  const lendingPoolAddress = event.args.pool; // Get the 'pool' parameter from the event

  console.log("Lending Pool Address:", lendingPoolAddress);
} else {
  console.log("PoolCreated event not found or missing arguments.");
}

Additional Debugging Tips:
Check the Full Receipt: To ensure your transaction receipt contains the events, you can print the entire receipt to examine the structure:
console.log(receipt);

Look for the event under receipt.events to ensure the PoolCreated event exists and that it contains the arguments you're trying to access.
Handling Multiple Events: If multiple events are fired and PoolCreated is one of many, you might need to refine how you search for it, such as by checking the contract address or signature.
Filter by Contract Address: If your contract emits multiple events, it may be useful to add a filter by contract address
const event = receipt.events.find((e) => e.event === "PoolCreated" && e.address === yourContractAddress

);
Verify Event Definition in the Contract
Ensure that your Solidity contract's event looks like this (or similar):
event PoolCreated(address indexed pool);

If you're emitting other parameters along with pool, adjust the event argument access accordingly.
This should help you isolate the issue and extract the event parameters successfully. Let me know if you need further assistance!
